# Data Explorer execution plans are no longer available because SHOWPLAN permission is denied

Tags: bug, data-explorer, sql, database-design

I noticed after a recent maintenance downtime that now I get the following message when trying to include an execution plan with a query:

> SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'StackOverflow'.

Was there a problem caused by this permission, and if so, what was it? It's very useful when trying to optimize a query.

This issue has resurfaced and been reopened as time has gone on, as noted in the following questions:

- [SHOWPLAN permission denied when including execution plan in Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260501/)
- ["SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'StackOverflow'." again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263456/)

Comment: The maintenance window involved an environment move, so I suspect this is a misconfiguration of the database user privileges on the other end.

Comment: @TimStone I just tried and it seems to be working again.

Comment: Not working at least since August 3, 2015. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261951

Comment: The close reason states "If you encounter a similar problem, please post a new question.". On the other hand, if a two year old question is closed five days ago, and the problem then somehow comes up again, I think it should be reopened.

Comment: @wythagoras: Does it? I checked and didn't have a problem. Is there a specific query that triggers this reliably?