# "SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'StackOverflow'." again

Tags: bug, status-reproduced, data-explorer

As has happened a [couple](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212979/215468) [times](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260501/215468), I'm seeing `SHOWPLAN permission denied in database 'StackOverflow'.` when trying to get an execution plan. I'm guessing this is an artifact of the recent Denver test.

It's not just Stack Overflow, I'm seeing it for all other sites.

Comment: This should be resolved going forward as it's now integrated into the database refresh job. However, there's another issue behind it also due to the Denver move: we're on a new version of SQL server and SEDE doesn't understand a few schema attributes. I'll try and update that today (still fighting a few higher-priority fires behind the scenes here).